# Why is there no PostgreSQL "user" table on Amazon EC2 Instance when it exists on my local device?

Tags: spring, postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I am running a spring boot instance on both local server and an EC2 instance.  I have it connected to a PostgreSQL database.  I receive an error message on the EC2 instance but not on the local device when running identical endpoints.  The local device succeeds but the EC2 instance produces this:

`o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "TABLENAME" does not exist Position: 21`

I used TABLENAME to make the message more anonymous for this post.

I receive this error in Postman upon the same request:

`JDBC exception executing SQL [select a1_0.id from \"TABLENAME\" a1_0 where a1_0.email is null fetch first ? rows only]; SQL [n/a]`

Help is appreciated.  I am wondering where the Spring Boot initializes the database and creates tables.  I am also wondering why this does not happen on the EC2 instance when it succeeds fine on the local device.

I am running a jar file on the EC2 instance and `mvn spring-boot:run` on the local device from source code if that makes a difference.

Comment: Is "TABLENAME" more anonymous than  "user"? It is hard to figure out what you are actually doing. Is this supposed to be two different database servers, or just two app servers connected to one database?

Comment: It is two separate instances of the same spring boot and postgres combination.  One instance is served locally, the other is served on an Amazon EC2 instance.